# Changing Cancel button Font in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm customizing a search bar and struggling to change the font of the "Cancel" button that pops in while typing in the search bar. So far, this is what I tried (casting UIView to UIBarButton fails):

```
for subView in controller.searchBar.subviews  {

    if let cancelButton = subView as? UIBarButtonItem {
        cancelButton.setTitleTextAttributes([ NSFontAttributeName: font ], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

swift:

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
     UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15, weight: UIFontWeightLight)], forState: .Normal)
} else {
     // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

Objective-C :

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                  [UIColor blueColor], 
                                                  UITextAttributeTextColor, 
                                                  [UIColor darkGrayColor], 
                                                  UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
                                                  [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)], 
                                                  UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                                  nil] 
                                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the view which holds your search bar, e.g.:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    // ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // ... other init code

        // search bar "Cancel" color
        searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor();

        // search bar "Cancel": custom text and font
        for sView in searchBar.subviews {
            for ssView in sView.subviews {
                if ssView.isKindOfClass(UIButton.self) {
                    let cancelButton = ssView as! UIButton
                    cancelButton.setTitle("Custom", forState: .Normal)
                    cancelButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "GillSans-BoldItalic", size: 14.0)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Yielding the following result:
[image]

For different fonts, see http://iosfonts.com, and for colours, see the [UIColor Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/).

Comment: Thanks, however I'm getting this error when running the app: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'`

Comment: @cb428 My mistake, I though the subview items were to be initialised in same order at all systems, but perhaps they are not. Edited with a safe (slightly uglier) solution.

Comment: Gotcha, hmm I must be doing something wrong on my end. I copy-pasted your edit and it still just shows the regular system font.

Comment: I forgot to mention: property `searchBar` is an `@IBOutlet` from the UISearchBar in your storyboard (to your view controller). Does this work for you?

Comment: I'm doing it programmatically using `let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)` then `controller.searchBar`

Comment: Ah I see. It still ought to work though. Try adding a `print("Entered here")` within the `if ssView.isKindOfClass(UIButton.self) { ... }` clause, to see if you even enter here.